# NSAttributedString - Space is not underlined at the end of each line

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want to underline each space with red, but the space at the end of each line is not underlined for some reason.

[image: image 1]

But the space is there, I can even highlight it:

[image: image 2]

Here is how I created the text view:

```
let textView = UITextView()
let text = "word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 word12"
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()
for char in text {
    if char == " " {
        attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: String(char), attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold), .underlineColor: UIColor.red, .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.thick.rawValue]))
    } else {
        attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: String(char), attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)]))
    }
}

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 8
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
attributedText.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paragraphStyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedText.length))

textView.attributedText = attributedText
textView.isEditable = false
textView.textContainerInset = .zero
```

Comment: Trailing whitespace of a line usually is not underlined - otherwise normal underlined text that spans multiple lines will look like their underlines are a little too long and doesn't fit the text perfectly. I don't think you should be using underlines like this. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: If you just want to draw a box under each of the spaces, you can explore the text view's [layout manager's methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager) and use them to find where the spaces are. (not sure if there's a better way)